# How to save and download locally csv in DBFS?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to save csv file as a result of SQL query, sent to Athena via Databricks.
The file is supposed to be a big table of about 4-6 GB (~40m rows).

I'm doing the next steps:

1. Creating PySpark dataframe by:

   ```
   df = sqlContext.sql("select * from my_table where year = 19")
   ```
2. Converting PySpark dataframe to Pandas dataframe. I realize, this step may be unnecessary, but I only start using Databricks and may not know the required commands to do it more swiftly. So I do it like this:

   ```
   ab = df.toPandas()
   ```
3. Save the file somewhere to download it locally later:

   ```
   ab.to_csv('my_my.csv')
   ```

But how do I download it?

I kindly ask you to be very specific as I do not know many tricks and details in working with Databricks.

Comment: Do you want to download the file to DBFS or to the local machine?

Comment: Eventually, I would like having the file locally on my machine.