# DataBricks Python save csv file and download it on my pc

Tags: python, azure, csv, download, databricks

I'm using DataBricks Python.

If I save this file

```
y_pred.to_csv("y_pred.csv")
```

it works but I don't know where the file is and I can't find it.

When I try to copy the file in another location

```
dbutils.fs.cp("/y_pred.csv", 'wasbs://...........')
```

I get the following error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /y_pred.csv

Comment: Specify the file path while saving `df.to_csv(r'/dir/y_pred.csv')` Reference: [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [Save results to csv file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345336/save-results-to-csv-file-with-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save and download locally csv in DBFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288111/how-to-save-and-download-locally-csv-in-dbfs)

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is the solution:

```
dbutils.fs.put('shared_uploads/...........com/y_pred.csv', pd.DataFrame(y_pred).to_csv())
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the databricks concepts , If data frame fits in a driver memory and you want to save to local files system ,that time we can use `to_csv`. So your file will be stored in driver node .
When you are reading the drive node local file through `dbutils.fs` we should add (`file:/<filelocation`). So try to read it like `dbutils.fs.cp("file:/y_pred.csv", 'wasbs://...........')` will it work . You can understand on  dbfs location [ref](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#summary-table-and-diagram)